# Saddle adjustment

Tags: saddle, adjustment

I was given a used specialized rock hopper last year but the seat angle is too high in the front. I've loosened the hex sockets beneath the saddle to adjust the angle but it always screws back in the same. Any help?

Comment: A photo of the clamp would be useful.

Comment: So there's a single bolt pointing upward into the saddle, behind the seatpost?  You may need to loosen it a lot more and tap the saddle to break it free.  The clamp may be bitten into the saddle rails, making it not move at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to loosen the correct bolts.. Its not the seat tube one (attached to the frame.) On most saddles these days there is just one or two bolts that allows for rail and angle position. If you have a forward and rear bolt fitting.. You need to loosen BOTH bolts.. otherwise the seat angle will likely stay the same. To lower the front of the saddle start to tighten the forward saddle bolt first and then the rear.. These bolts are effectively a cradle system so adjusting one has an effect on the other,  you just set the appropriate seat angle and ballance the bolt torque evenly..

If the rocker has stuck... Loosen the adjustment bolt/bolts quite a bit,  then use either a plastic mallet or small hammer and piece of wood to tap on the adjustment rocker, this should loosen it up and allow you to adjust the saddle angle.

Comment: To lower the front of the saddle you loosen the rear bolt by half a turn and tighten the front bolt by another half turn. Repeat until the position is correct and check both bolts for the correct torque.

Comment: Thanks, bike peeps! I'll try these solutions out & return to relate what worked best...BC